# Transect profile plot matlab

Tags: geoprocessing, remote-sensing

I have 3D matrix file where XYZ are lon,lat and height. I plot these XYZ value using scatter3. Now I want to plot profile of height (along a line in km) of the data where xaxis:distance along line in km and yaxis:Z value . I tried mapprofile and improfile but could not able to get what I want.